# Using C++ DLL in D10

Tags: c++, delphi, dllimport

I use a C++ DLL in my app.

```
type
  Tcl_bla = function(filename: PChar): Integer; cdecl;

var
  cl_bla: Tcl_bla;

function CallLibraryProc(Proc: String): Pointer;
begin
  Result := GetProcAddress(Handle, PChar(Proc));
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    Loaded := False;
  if not Loaded then
    MessageBox(0, PChar('Error => ' + Proc), 'Alert', MB_OK or MB_TOPMOST);
end;
...    
Handle := SafeLoadLibrary(
  PChar(CurrentPath + Dll),
  SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS or SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX or SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX
);
if (Handle < HINSTANCE_ERROR) then
  raise Exception.Create(
    Dll + ' library can not be loaded or not found.' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)
  );
if Handle <> 0 then
begin
  // blabla  
  cl_bla := CallLibraryProc('cl_bla');
end;
...    
FreeLibrary(Handle);
```

The codes aboves works fine with D6. I'm trying to port my code so it can run in Delphi with Unicode support but I have a trouble.

I've read the documentation from Embarcadero about GetProcAddress

```
procedure CallLibraryProc(const LibraryName, ProcName: string);
var
  Handle: THandle;
  RegisterProc: function: HResult stdcall;
begin
  Handle := LoadOleControlLibrary(LibraryName, True);
  @RegisterProc := GetProcAddress(Handle, PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ProcName)));
end;
```

I can't try this because I don't know how to declare LoadOleControlLibrary!

My CallLibraryProc can load the DLL but somehow cl_bla works incorrectly.

I think the problem with my code because of GetProcAddress's parameter or.. maybe my ported header is wrong.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to believe that "the codes above" really work find since the function named `CallLibraryProc` doesn't actually call the library proc.

Comment: Could you sort the indentation out please. The code is quite hard to read like this!

Comment: @David, Tools - Options - Indentation. Ugh sorry I don't get it :(

Comment: the indentation of the question. Just take a look at it. Looking like that is going to put people off reading. Although this question already has its answer!!

Comment: @David Ugh my English is poor, (sorry) can you just change it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may as well post this this as an answer, because it seems like the answer!

The code that you say is D6 code will work fine unmodified in D2010, and have the same meaning.  There are two `GetProcAddress` overloads in Windows.pas. One of them converts from Unicode to ANSI. So you can just call `GetProcAddress(Handle, PChar(Proc))` just like you always did.

The *magic* one looks like this:

```
function GetProcAddress(hModule: HMODULE; lpProcName: LPCWSTR): FARPROC;
begin
  if ULONG_PTR(lpProcName) shr 16 = 0 then // IS_INTRESOURCE
    Result := GetProcAddress(hModule, LPCSTR(lpProcName))
  else
    Result := GetProcAddress(hModule, LPCSTR(AnsiString(lpProcName)));
end;
```

Comment: Yes my code doesn't have any error in D2010 but the imported functions from DLL works incorrectly. Does it mean my function declarations (cl_bla) are wrong? Because I don't change my function declarations at all.

Comment: @user Your problem is not in the D6 code that you posted. That works unchanged. I can't be sure what your problem really is, but I suspect the errors occur when you call the procedures rather than when you call `GetProcAddress`. You are probably passing Unicode strings to a DLL that expects ANSI strings. Have you changed the DLL?

Comment: I haven't changed the DLL and I hope I don't. Your suspect probably true, I tried to change my declaration, some function return Chinese message box. I think I have tried to change all PChar to PAnsiChar in my code. Does passing (D6) pointer can occur the error?

Comment: @user You can leave the DLL as an ANSI DLL. Here's what you do. In the Delphi code, each import from the DLL needs to use PAnsiChar rather than PChar. Then when you call those functions you pass `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Text))` rather than `PChar(Text)`.

Comment: Okay your answer is the solution. I hope I can fix it after I sleep. 2 am here :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare or use `LoadOleControlLibrary`. Just call plain old `LoadLibrary` like you always have. The important part of the code you saw was to convert Delphi's `UnicodeString` values into `AnsiString` values, and then type-cast explicitly to `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar`. (`PChar` is `PWideChar` nowadays, and `GetProcAddress` requires non-Unicode characters.) I suggest changing `ProcName` to declare it as an `AnsiString` from the beginning. You'll need less type-casting. Keep `LibraryName` declared as `string`.

Comment: Actually there are two `GetProcAddress` overloads in Windows.pas. One of them converts from Unicode to ANSI. So you can just call `GetProcAddress(Lib, PChar(ProcName))`.

Comment: I need a little time to try your answer. Actually I have tried but I still fail to fix my code. Is it possible to paste some code in this comment box?